# Invoking JavaScript function after AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Apologies for the confusion, please see simplified example below. I know how to do this with JQuery using its dynamic structure :

**This works after being inserted as .innerHTML:**

```
<button class='ctrl_row'>Click Me</button>

$(document).on("click", ".ctrl_row", function(){
    //do something
});
```

**This doesn't work after being inserted as .innerHTML:**

```
<button onclick='preview()'>Click Me</button>

function preview() {
    //do something
}
```

I have a decent amount of pure JavaScript (not JQuery) written in a php loop (lots of getElementById's), it works so i don't want to convert it, so how do i get **pure javascript** to work after being loaded by AJAX?

Comment: Stick with jQuery if you already have it.

Comment: @ComFreek The problem is a already have it done in JavaScript using onkeyup events, if there is a method which would load the function after AJAX had finished that would be the solution i am looking for else it will take me hours to convert.

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript! You can mix it!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The click handler can contain code with pure javascript. `this` inside the handler is a raw element object, not a jquery object. `e` is some kind of jquery thing, but `e.originalEvent` is the non-jquery event you know and love.

Comment: @DavidKnipe please see updated question, hopefully it explains it more thoroughly.

Comment: Ugh. Don't generate Javascript on the server side. It's pretty much never necessary and almost always leads to confusing behaviour. Delegated event handlers work for elements created dynamically. (It just so happens jQuery makes using them convenient, but it's nothing you can't replicate.) You can also make your AJAX code bind events to the newly inserted elements "manually".

Comment: For what it's worth, your jQuery snippet is already using delegated events which is why it works. (Possibly the reason it works is because that code is also present in the original HTML before the AJAX call.) It's also using them badly since you register the same event handler who knows how many times, and registers it on `document` which is somewhat bad for performance. But anyway, the point is the two snippets aren't equivalent.

Comment: @millimoose Ok so say i was willing to use JQuery to do this, all i would have to do is invoke the preview function in the same way i would in JQuery and keep my original code inside? You have concerned me saying "It's also using them badly since you register the same event handler who knows how many times", is that based on how many times i load the same content? If not how can i prevent that behaviour? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this in your *success* callback. First insert the button using **.innerHTML** like:

```
<button id="buttonId">Click Me</button>
```

Then, you can bind the event in pure javascript using the following event handlers:

```
var button = document.getElementById("buttonId");

if (button.addEventListener)
    button.addEventListener("click", yourhandlerfunction, false);
else if (button.attachEvent)
    button.attachEvent ("onclick", yourhandlerfunction);
```

You can read more about it [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener). Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Case analysis like this is ugly and error-prone. This is why we use jQuery :-)

Comment: Agree, even I also prefer JQuery. But, the _asker_ wanted the solution in pure JS. So, had to answer keeping this in mind. :)

Comment: Yes, I realise that. But if we nag them enough maybe they'll see reason :-)

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here sans any dependency on frameworks...

[Does this Ajax method work in many browsers and operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986800/does-this-ajax-method-work-in-many-browsers-and-operating-systems/18988763#18988763)

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `append('yourhtmlajaxresponse')` function instead of `.innerHTML` for events to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code in pure js:

```
var req;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    req=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    req=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
req.open("POST", "url to the reqst page", true);
    req.send();
    req.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(req.readyState==4&&req.status==200){

                //here you will get the result from the reqst page after execution
        }
}
```

put this code inside a function and call whenever you need.

Comment: Thanks for this, i already have ajax working, i just need JavaScript to work afterwards

Comment: Where is this code from? You didn't write it. I recognise it. It comes from a terrible source called w3schools. Why else would you include a compatibility fix for IE5 and IE6?

Comment: I am using this code in my project working fine..
You are right I did'nt write this code now but copied from my project.