# XML import into html doesnt work from url

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to show XML data into the table. Script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var xhr= window.XMLHttpRequest? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (this.readyState===4 || this.status===200)
            populateTable(this.responseXML);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://imenicka.cz/xml/menicko.php?hash=fccab45d85b39726611ab433f66263a7&restaurace=430&datum=2013-10-02', true);
    xhr.send();

    function populateTable(xml) {
        var table= document.getElementById('cds');
        var cds= xml.getElementsByTagName('MENICKO');
        for (var i= 0; i<cds.length; i++) {
            var row= table.insertRow(-1);

            function getProperty(name) {
                var el= cds[i].getElementsByTagName(name)[0];
                if (el.firstChild)
                    return el.firstChild.data;
                return ''; // allow empty elements
            }
            function addCell(value) {
                row.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
            }

            addCell(getProperty('TEXT'));
            addCell(getProperty('CENA'));
        }
    };

</script>
```

It doesn´t work if I want to import data from

`xhr.open('GET', 'http://imenicka.cz/xml/menicko.php?hash=fccab45d85b39726611ab433f66263a7&restaurace=430&datum=2013-10-02', true);`.

But if I take the data from the folder then it does.

```
xhr.open('GET', 'menicka.xml', true);
```

I don´t know that much about javascript so I can´t figure it out.

Comment: See my answer here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986800/does-this-ajax-method-work-in-many-browsers-and-operating-systems/18988763#18988763

Answer (score 0):

The response from `http://imenicka.cz/xml/menicko.php?hash=fccab45d85b39726611ab433f66263a7&restaurace=430&datum=2013-10-02` is of type `text/html`, rather than `application/xml`.

This means the response it not treated as XML and `responseXML` will be empty.

You can test this by adding an alert here:

```
//...
alert(this.responseXML);
populateTable(this.responseXML);
//...
```

See [a running demo of this on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LC2Zs/).