# Way to detect browser / platform through ajax request in PHP

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I already have a published app in both iOS and Android using Cordova. I'm using PHP scripts to retrieve and send data from server. Both platforms use same PHP script. I send data using XML. And call this script using AJAX.

a sample ajax call :

```
jQuery.ajax({
                          url: 'http://www.example.net/example.php',  //load data 
                          global: false,
                          type: "POST",
                          dataType: "xml",
                          async: true,
                          beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#loading').show();
                          },
                          complete: function(){
                            $('#loading').hide();
                          },
                          success: loading_complete_list,
                          error: errorfunc
                    });
```

Problem is I have to send some **platform specific data**. That means I need to send some specific data for ANDROID. I can't change app code as **user may or may not update** the app. So I have to **change the PHP script** such a way that it'll detect the ajax requesting platform or browser and send specific data. So far I know that iOS and Android uses specific webview such as safari or chromium. So if I can at least detect the requesting browser I can detect the platform.

Please remember I can't change app code as it's already published and I can't force user to update. Thus it has to be detected using the PHP script.

I tried searching detect browser using php for ajax call, but no luck so far. Is it possible to detect browser / platform through ajax call in PHP? If so then how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18988763/552116

Comment: nope, it's not near the thing I'm looking for @soul

Comment: Have you tried PHP's get_browser function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: This answer should give you what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383776/detect-in-app-browser-webview-with-php-javascript

Comment: I will try and let you guys know

Comment: @JasonatFloSports sorry for late, it worked. post as an answer, i'll accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

Comment: No I can't. I'm written in my question clearly that I can't modify app code, JS code can't be changed. It has to be identified by PHP only. no passing.